# get value from a service, that have observable, Angular google map API

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, rxjs, observable

I create an angular project where I need to add a map component to the project. I have a service file, `map.service.ts` where my service to google map API is integrated, I wanted to draw circles(polygon) in the map and pass values to the backend, there I have added few event listeners such circlecomplete,radius_changed..etc.. .this is where my services start.

```
 public initMap(mapElement: ElementRef, search: ElementRef, options: MapOptions) {
    return this.init().pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        this.createGoogleMap(mapElement.nativeElement, search.nativeElement, options)
      ),
      exhaustMap(() =>
        forkJoin(
          this.subscribeToDrawingEvents('circlecomplete').pipe(
            map(d => console.log(d))
            ),
          this.subscribeToCenterChangeEvents('center_changed').pipe(
              map(d => console.log(d))
              ),
          this.subscribeToRadiusChangeEvents('radius_changed').pipe(
                map(d => console.log(d))
                ),
          this.subscribeToSearchboxEvents('places_changed')
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

in the intimap method, I created the JS , then append to the component. then crateGoogleMap create the map. then added few event listeners. I subscribe to this service from a `map.component.ts`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.option = {
      center: this.center ? this.center : { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
      zoom: this.zoom ? this.zoom : 4,
      markers: this.markers ? this.markers : []
    };
    this.subscribe_event$ = this.service.initMap(this.googleMap, this.searchInput, this.option);
    this.subscribe_event$.subscribe();
  } // ngOnInit()
```

I could get values to the d

```
 this.subscribeToCenterChangeEvents('center_changed').pipe(
          map(d => console.log(d))
          ),
```

section but I can't get values to the component. where I subscribe.
this is my observer....

```
private subscribeToCenterChangeEvents<E>(eventName: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Circle Center Change listner added');
    return Observable.create((obsever: Observer<any>) => {
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.drawingManager, eventName, drwnCircle => {
        const circle_radius: Number = drwnCircle.getRadius();
        const circle_center: LatLng = drwnCircle.getCenter();
        console.log(circle_radius);
        obsever.next({ drwan_circle: circle_radius });
      });
    });
  } // subscribeToCenterChangeEvents
```

Comment: i want to get values to the component,,, some where in ... this.subscribe_event$.subscribe();

Comment: try `this.subscribe_event$ = this.service.initMap(this.googleMap, this.searchInput, this.option).subscribe(res => console.log(res));`

Comment: thank you @JacopoSciampi. i will giv a shot

Comment: I tried this. The thing is subscibe doesn't get the value... only could add the event listner to the map.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `subscribe` method, assign the values to a variable.

```
resValues: your_Type;
this.subscribe_event$.subscribe((response) => {
    this.resValues = response; 
});
```

Comment: thank you for your time..I tried this earlier but it doesnt recieve the response. i wonder whether do we need to return that data from the map.services.ts in  `initMap`  method

Comment: Ahh yes, u do. But if u just want to print console log in their, just use `tap` instead of `map`

Comment: yha... thank you.. i wanted to check whether value is available.